# Backup System State from service

Tags: c#, service

I try to Backup System State Service on Windows Server:

```
string path = "D:";
string wbadminPath = Environment.SystemDirectory + @"\wbadmin";
string wbadminEvent = "start systemstatebackup -backupTarget:" + path + " -quiet";

    try
    {
        int exitCode = 0;
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo(wbadminPath, wbadminEvent);
        using (Process proc = Process.Start(start))
        {
            proc.WaitForExit();
            exitCode = proc.ExitCode;                    
        }
    }
```

It works! But when I try to run this code in WindowsService, Windows Server show me this exception:

> *Command Line Interface for Microsoft BLB Backup has stopped working Problem signature: Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH Application
>   Name: wbadmin.exe Application Version:    6.0.6001.18000 Application
>   Timestamp:    47918aed Fault Module Name: kernel32.dll Fault Module
>   Version:  6.0.6002.18327 Fault Module Timestamp:  4cb73436 Exception
>   Code: c0000142 Exception Offset:  00009f7d OS
>   Version:  6.0.6002.2.2.0.274.10 Locale ID:    1033 Additional Information
>   1:    9d13 Additional Information 2:  1abee00edb3fc1158f9ad6f44f0f6be8
>   Additional Information 3: 9d13 Additional Information
>   4:    1abee00edb3fc1158f9ad6f44f0f6be8*

Comment: What user are you running the service as? does it have sufficient rights?

Comment: I used Administrator's account in both cases (console application and service).

Comment: Where is the backup path you're targetting? local drive?

Comment: Yes, the same local drive (D:) in both cases (console app and service)

Comment: Only thing I found was http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/stop-c0000142-dll-initialization-failed/75db78d1-a051-4de3-822e-fc923fa82f85?auth=1

Comment: Maybe this is not possible, - to do Backup System State through WinService?